# How to save value in NSSet Core Data (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-data

I have to Entity in and both are connected.

[image]

I want to insert value in Company entity value but i have no idea how to insert value in company.employees(NSSet).

Both Employees and Company classes are given below:

```
extension Employees {

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var age: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var address: String?
@NSManaged var company: Company?

}

extension Company {

@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var employees: NSSet?

}


// here i want to insert value 

    func addEmployees() {

    let companyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Company", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let company = Company(entity: companyEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    company.name = txtCompany.text


    let employeesEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employees", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let employees = Employees(entity: employeesEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    employees.name = txtName.text
    employees.age = Int(txtAge.text!)
    employees.address = txtAddress.text

    // getting no idea here how to save values to NSSet??
//  company.employees =




    do {
        try managedContext.save()            

    } catch {
        fatalError("Error in saving Data...")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's always easier to do it from the other end:

```
employees.company = company
```

Core data will take care of the many side of the relationship because you've specified the inverse relationship in your data model.

Also, rename your entity. It should be called `Employee`, since each entity represents one employee. It will save you a lot of confusion down the road.

If you really insist on editing it from the company end, you do it like this:

```
company.mutableSetValueForKey("employees").addObject(employees)
```

Which I hope you'll agree is significantly uglier and more prone to errors.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to do it from company.employees which is type off NSSet

Comment: Using my answer will have the exactly the same result, except you don't need to mess about with sets.

Comment: @S.Bharti you will alreadyl have the `Company` and `Employee` to be able to create the relationship. Just define the relationship the other way around. It does the same thing either way and this way is easier to code.

Comment: OK Thanks for fast reply i will use employee.company but if i  have to do the second methode so how can it be done???

Comment: @S.Bharti you should never "have" to do the other method. Purely because that it can always be done the easy way. The way to do it though is to create an NSMutableSet from the company's employees and then add the new employee before then setting the company's employees to the new edited set.

Comment: I added the other method for you since you seem very keen on seeing it. But I _never_ do it that way unless I have no option (e.g. a many-to-many relationship)

Answer (score 0):

I know there are some substantial amount of up votes for jrturton's answer, but as the poser has emphasized it should be done in the other way around. Therefore, let me show how its done.

1. The Company could have 0 or many employees (ideally 1 or many)
2. Since NSSet accepts an array as one of its constructers employees should be in a form of an array. Therefore, we gonna create an instance of an array of Employees and append them and then convert it to an NSSet.

   ```
   func addEmployees() {

   let companyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Company", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
   let company = Company(entity: companyEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
   company.name = txtCompany.text


   let employeesEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employees", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
   let employees = Employees(entity: employeesEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

   //Add this 
    var all_employees = [Employees]()

    employees.name = txtName.text
    employees.age = Int(txtAge.text!)
    employees.address = txtAddress.text

    //Finally
    all_employees.appned(employees)
    company.employees = NSSet(array: all_employees!)


    do {
         try managedContext.save()            

    } catch {
         fatalError("Error in saving Data...")
    }


    }
   ```