# Working with Coredata relationship NSSet Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

Beginner here, I try to do (`toPropAddress` is an `NSSet`)

```
let currentAddresses = currentOwner.toPropAddress!.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableSet
currentAddresses.addObject(currentAddress)
```

it works

but if i do 
`let currentAddresses = currentOwner.toPropAddress! as! NSMutableSet`
leaving out the `.mutableCopy` it will not work, as everything saves, but my new object is not connected with the owner.

Can anyone explain why this is?

I already know `toPropAddress` is immutable but i thought setting it as `NSMutableSet` solve that problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save value in NSSet Core Data (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674416/how-to-save-value-in-nsset-core-data-swift)

Comment: i am not asking "how" to save

Comment: If you read the question rather than just the title you'll see that it is about writing to-many relationships.